# Where can I find Amazon Linux AMI Image for VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to learn AWS and because I'm some familiar with Linux, I think the best way to learn is to get Amazon Linux AMI right into VirtualBox software and play with it.

I see the latest Amazon Linux AMI by date is **2012.09** and as my question suggest if is there a page where Amazon maintains a hierarchy of all images released to date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use AMIs in Virtualbox -- there's no way to export an AMI such that this would be possible.

You can find a list of all AMIs [here](https://aws.amazon.com/amis). Note that most of them haven't been released by Amazon, but by a third party.

Comment: So what close to AMI I can use with VirtualBox and then put my stuff there on AWS? Debian or Fedora?

Comment: You can create AMIs only on the Amazon cloud.

Comment: I mean among Fedora and Debian which is closest to AMI?

Comment: Depends on the AMI. An AMI is simply a disk image with some metadata, it can be any distribution or Windows or something rlse.

Comment: Amazon Linux is similar to (but not the same as) RHEL and CentOS.

Comment: they make linux-amazon-2 available now

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an older question but you can now download pre-rolled HD images of Amazon linux for VMWare, VirtualBox, and HyperV here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-2-virtual-machine.html You have to create a meta ISO with user data to help with the install but it should be possible to create a working local Amazon Linux instance for testing.

** EDIT**

I found [this repo](https://github.com/monetate/ectou-export) which worked great for me creating a Virtualbox .box image for Vagrant. Oddly, the image doesn't work when trying to import into Vagrant on Windows but I think that's a Virtualbox bug. It looks like there is a minor bug w/ the scripts when trying to install guest additions which I'm working on a PR for.

** EDIT **

The repo was updated for proper guest additions AND has added VMWare support.

Answer (score 2):

You can also extract the AMI via creating an instance and install packer. http://www.packer.io/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to give more context here in the answer, and provide the link only for reference.